# Silent MSI uninstall dont remove installation folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I created an empty project, with a visual studio msi installer. On install it just creates the folder and the exe file to the project.

But when i am trying to silent uninstall, it remove the installation from program list, but it leaves the folder. I need to remove the folder as well and want to do this without deleting it manually in code.

```
   // This is how to uninstall a basic msi app

        // Create the uninstall process.
        Process proc = new Process();

        // Define the parameters for the process
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";

        // This is the Product Code from your Basic MSI InstallShield Project

        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "/x" + " " + ProductCode + " " + "/qn";

        // Start the process.
        proc.Start();

        // Wait for the uninstall process to end.
        proc.WaitForInputIdle();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        // Release resources.
        proc.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruct the MSI to output a log file using the [`/L logfile.txt`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#BKMK_SetLogging) command line option for `msiexec`. It should tell you why the uninstaller cannot remove the installation file. Possible causes include the folder being locked (requiring a reboot to remove) or file permissions on the folder preventing deletion. See [Wix installer could not remove installation folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102256/wix-installer-could-not-remove-installation-folder) or [Installshield, uninstalling program not removing all folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949840/installshield-uninstalling-program-not-removing-all-folders) for more information.